# How to make container overflow on only x axis when it contains absolutely positioned content?

Tags: css

I have a custom dropdown box that uses absolute positioning for the list of items. This sits within a table row. When the viewport is not wide enough to contain the table I want it to automatically scroll on the X axis.

The problem I have is that, as per the spec if I add `overflow-x: auto;` to the parent container and try to set `overflow-y: visible;` it sets this axis to auto. This causes the Y axis to scroll.

Example:
https://codepen.io/afisher88/pen/mdJybaY

**HTML**

```
<div class="outer-wrapper">
  <div class="inner-wrapper">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>One</th>
          <th>Two</th>
          <th>Three</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>One</td>
          <td>
            <div class="custom-dropdown">
              <button id="btn" type="button">Toggle dropdown!</button>
              <ul>
                <li>Option</li>
                <li>Option</li>
                <li>Option</li>
                <li>Option</li>
                <li>Option</li>
              </ul>        
            </div>
          </td>
          <td><input type="text"/></td>              
          <td>WFaouhfgeaouhgaeoghuaegoauehgaoeguhaegouhaegoaehugaeoguhaeg</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

**SCSS**

```
.outer-wrapper {
  background: #f2f2f2;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: visible;

}

.custom-dropdown {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  background: #fff;

    &.open {
    ul {
      display: block;
    }
  }

  button {
    display: block;
    border: 0;
    box-shadow: 0;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 5px;
    height: 30px;
  }

  ul {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    top: 14px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background: #fff;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

*Edit*: To answer the comment about padding and breaking positioning, since you're using Sass, set a variable for the padding of the container (at least where bottom padding is being used) and use that in the following `transform`.

- Remove `position: relative;` from `.custom-dropdown`
- Remove `left: 0` from `.custom-dropdown`
- Remove `top: 14px;` from `.custom-dropdown ul`
- Add `transform: translateY(-$padding)` where `$padding` is a Sass variable for the container padding (if any).
- Refactor `width: 100%;` to `width: 10em;` (to match cell width) in `.custom-dropdown ul` (personal preference)

I also added a light border around the `ul` for some added UX.

```js
const btn = document.getElementById('btn');

console.log(btn);
  
btn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  e.target.parentElement.classList.toggle('open');
});
```

```css
.outer-wrapper {
  background: #f2f2f2;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: visible;
  padding: 1em; /* Sass variable simulation */
}

.custom-dropdown {
  /*position: relative;*/
  width: 200px;
  background: #fff;
}

.custom-dropdown.open ul {
  display: block;
  z-index: 10;
}
  
.custom-dropdown button {
  display: block;
  border: 0;
  box-shadow: 0;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  height: 30px;
}
  
.custom-dropdown ul {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  /* left: 0; */
  width: 10em;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  transform: translateY(-1em); /* Sass variable simulation */
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-wrapper">
  <div class="inner-wrapper">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>One</th>
          <th>Two</th>
          <th>Three</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>One</td>
          <td>
            <div class="custom-dropdown">
              <button id="btn" type="button">Toggle dropdown!</button>
              <ul>
                <li>Option</li>
                <li>Option</li>
                <li>Option</li>
                <li>Option</li>
                <li>Option</li>
              </ul>        
            </div>
          </td>
          <td><input type="text"/></td>              
          <td>WFaouhfgeaouhgaeoghuaegoauehgaoeguhaegouhaegoaehugaeoguhaeg</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you change the positioning of custom-dropdown to "relative" it's position won't relate to the "custom-dropdown" container anymore. If you add padding to the outer wrapper for example all of the positioning will break.

Comment: @Antfish I have edited the answer to account for this, which should make it easy since you're using Sass  i.e. variable for container padding. This could be done with CSS variables as well without Sass.

Comment: This works vertically but the dropdown container still scrolls horizontally:https://codepen.io/afisher88/pen/xxGwPpW